# Meaning of "About not very much."

Tags: meaning-in-context

From the book 100-year-old man who climbed out the window and disappeared.

> "Allan was beginning to tire of Stalin's touchness. The old geezer was quite red in the face with anger , but **about not very much**. Stalin went on ."

From the above sentence what does *'about not very much mean'*?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If a situation or general thing is causing you to feel angry, you can say you are *angry about* it.

> I am angry about losing the game.

In the example sentence, the writer is saying Stalin was angry, but about something that is *not very much*, meaning something minor or trivial.